# latex error Missing $ inserted

Tags: latex

I'm trying to use LaTeX to write my math notes. But I have some problems.

The error is written:

> LaTeX error Missing $ inserted

And it doesn't compile correctly:

[image]

```
\documentclass[french,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\author{
  Alexandre Monterroso\\
 Université de Fribourg\\
}
\newtheorem{de}{Définition}[subsection] 
\newtheorem{theo}{Théorème}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[theo]{Proposition}


\begin{document}
\section{Combinatoris}
\subsection{Ordered choices}
\begin{itemize}
    \item With repetition
\end{itemize}
\begin{theo}
The number of lists (a_{1}, ..., a_{k}) of k not necessarly distincts objects elements (ie. with repetition) from a set n elements is a^{k} (n, k \epsilon N).
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify math-related content in math mode. So, use

```
The number of lists ($a_1, \dots, a_k$) of~$k$ not necessarily dist ...
```

`$`...`$` initiated and closes in-line math mode, while `\[`...`\]` initiates and closes display math mode.

Comment: Thanks, the pdf is right now. But I have the errors in the console at compilation. Command \end{theo} invalid in math mode. Or something wrong --perhaps a missing \item.

Comment: @ale252: You need to place all math content in math mode, as I already mentioned. Make sure though that when you open math mode somewhere in a group, that you also close it within the same group.